# Spring Boot Configuration Bean behaves different at Windows and Linux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-session

I am using `openjdk14` and have interesting problem here. I have `reactive project` and use `spring security` and `spring session` modules. I have created my `WebSessionManager` as described here. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#websession-how)

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@Slf4j
public class SpringWebSessionConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private WebSessionIdResolver webSessionIdResolver;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;

    @Bean(WebHttpHandlerBuilder.WEB_SESSION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public WebSessionManager webSessionManager(ReactiveSessionRepository<? extends Session> repository) {
       log.info("line 1");
       ...
       return manager;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When I try to compile and run in my local computer `(windows 10)`, my bean is created successfully and I see "line 1" log, so everything is `fine`. But when i try to compile and run in `linux (centos 8)` instead, my bean is `not created` so i cannot see "line 1" log.

Here is the windows log

> 2020-12-08 17:36:51.371 DEBUG 8368 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition
> for bean 'webSessionManager' with a different definition: replacing
>
> factoryBeanName=org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.server.RedisWebSessionConfiguration;
> factoryMethodName=webSessionManager; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>
> [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/server/RedisWebSessionConfiguration.class]]
>
> factoryBeanName=springWebSessionConfiguration;
> factoryMethodName=webSessionManager; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>
> [com/yte/apigateway/logout/configuration/SpringWebSessionConfiguration.class]]

here is the linux log

> 2020-12-08 17:39:40.750 DEBUG 1700 --- [           main]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition
> for bean 'webSessionManager' with a different definition: replacing
>
> factoryBeanName=springWebSessionConfiguration;
> factoryMethodName=webSessionManager; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>
> [com/yte/apigateway/logout/configuration/SpringWebSessionConfiguration.class]]
>
> factoryBeanName=org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.server.RedisWebSessionConfiguration;
> factoryMethodName=webSessionManager; initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>
> [org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/server/RedisWebSessionConfiguration.class]]

`Linux and Windows are picking different configuration` as you can see in logs. Has anyone encountered a similar error before ? It think it must be `bug on java`. How can I report this? Would you try same configuration if possible to be sure?

Here are my dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

...

<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gateway-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Is the bean really not created or is there simply no logging due to log levels being different or logging setup is different?

Comment: @M.Deinum i updated my question and added logs. linux and windows are picking different configuration.

Comment: Do you have a redis running on both plattforms?

Comment: @Toerktumlare no, i have only one running redis instace at linux. i am using this in windows too.

Comment: Cause it looks like one can find redis, the other can’t

Comment: @Toerktumlare when i login to app, it stores sessions on redis, so it seems there is no issue on redis connection.